# Office 2013 Word indentation

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm having an issue with indents.

I can't seem to remove the indent shown in the image here:

[image: Problem]

Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem:

- Go to `View -> Outline`
- Now keep Cursor on the line you want to change the indent. In your case the line containing the word `> Background`. You need not to select the line, only keeping the cursor on that line will be fine.
- Now Use Keyboard Shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to change the heading left or right. In your case you have to shift it to left.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a normal list then I think the most reliable method is to copy format from the line below ("RISK FACTORS").

- Select the whole "RISK FACTORS" line
- Press Ctrl + Shift + C
- Select the whole "BACKGROUND" line
- Press Ctrl + Shift + V

If this is the autogenerated table of contents then you should change (decrease) outline level for the element in the main text ("BACKGROUND") and regenerate the TOC.